# OpenLink Virtuoso vs Virtuoso Universal Server

Tags: database, nosql, virtuoso

I'm inclined for OpenLink Virtuoso at the moment since it's open source.

However, does Virtuoso Universal Server (commercial) have more features compared to OpenLink Virtuoso (open source) or are they [very] similar? Am I missing something if I use OpenLink Virtuoso and don't upgrade to the commercial "Virtuoso Universal Server"?

I'm sorry to ask, but the web pages are not clear enough for me. I can't get any clear cut answer from the online documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about comparisons between two products from the same company, OpenLink Software (my employer).

In short, yes, Virtuoso Enterprise Edition a/k/a Commercial Edition has several features that are not in Virtuoso Open Source Edition a/k/a VOS.  Significant differences include Custom Inference Rules, Attribute-Based Access Control (ABAC), Rule-Based Access Control for RDF Named Graphs, Federation/Virtualization of external SQL and RDF data sources, Replication Cluster options, Elastic/"Shared-Nothing" Cluster options, and more.  We publish a useful [feature comparison matrix](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/), comparing VOS with Enterprise Edition from v5 to v8 (current).

All that said, you can start with VOS and migrate to Enterprise Edition if and when you discover a need for the Enterprise features, just by replacing the executables; the database does typically not need to be rebuilt.  (Reverse migration is possible but takes more work, and this direction *always* requires a dump and reload, at minimum.)  Similarly, you can start with a low-scale Enterprise license, and upgrade when/if you need to support more users, use more processors, add optional features, etc.  You don't pay twice, as scale-upgrade licenses are priced at the difference between the existing and the new.

More details about any of the above are best gathered through the  [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com/) or by contacting [our Sales team](https://www.openlinksw.com/contact).